# Syntax error in loopback api gateway

Tags: node.js, gateway, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am following a tutorial :http://strongloop.com/strongblog/node-js-loopback-api-gateway-sample-applications/

and I am getting an error in the code underneath the **Proxy** heading in the link mentioned above.

Code against the error is

```
var proxy = require('./middleware/proxy');
var proxyOptions = require('./middleware/proxy/config.json');
app.use(proxy(proxyOptions));
{
 "rules": [
 "^/api/(.*)$ http://localhost:3002/api/$1 [P]"
          ]
}
```

the error message is 
[image]

is there any thing wrong with the json?

Comment: The JSON is fine, but you are not passing it to any function, so it is being parsed as a block, not an object. What are you trying to do with it? Did you mean to pass it to the `proxy` function perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Problem is solved the problem was that I did not run the API Server **http://localhost:3002** where the request was to be sent. I was only running the proxy server whereas there should be an API Server running also to which the request was to be sent.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just copied and pasted the code from that blog post, but that was not intended to be runnable code, it was just a snippet to illustrate that you could proxy requests. I think the blog post could be a lot more clear (I'll ping the author of it separately). That said, we have an [example project](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-proxy) which has some actual code that shows you how you might proxy actual requests.

If you're just trying to get a basic example working, then you probably don't even need those lines in your application JS file, so I'd just remove them entirely.

If you *do* need to proxy requests, take a look at the example project I linked to above, specifically the [`proxy` middleware](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-proxy/blob/master/middleware/proxy.js) they have in it.